# Images of Lines

Tags: geometry, transformation, transformational-geometry

I'm studying for this exam and one of the questions I am stuck on is:

Find the image of the line
$$3x-y+1 = 0$$
under the transformation
$$z \mapsto \frac{2}{z+1}$$

So I know I have to convert the formula for a line into complex form and then substitute the transformation into that formula. But I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The transformation is a Moebius transform, and as such it maps lines and circles to lines and circles.  Any line or circle is characterized by knowing three points along it.  So pick three points on your line, and see where they are mapped to by the transformation.

Comment: So if I have (0,1), (1,4), and (-1,-2)... what do I do to that?

I plug it into the transformation, but how do I find the image of the line? Shouldn't the ultimate formula be just one thing?

Thanks.

Comment: So you plug $i$, $1+4i$ and $-1-2i$ into the transformation.  That gives you three points on the circle.  I guess one way to find the circle is to start with the equation $(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=r^2$, put in the three points, and solve the three equations for three unknowns.